# Editing source from a Visual Studio 2008 project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

I work in a large team, and not everybody has upgraded from VS 2008 to VS 2010, though I have. I have a maintenance bug in a VS 2008 project, and have been told that I cannot upgrade the project file. Is there a way for me to make the changes I need to make within VS10 without upgrading the project (including compiling, using the debugger, etc.), or do I need to re-install VS 2008?

Comment: Are you saying you *uninstalled* vs2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool to switch project files between using Visual Studio 2008 and 2010

http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2010/02/tool-to-switch-project-files-between.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could go ahead and upgrade the solution, but not check it in. Wouldn't work?

However, being a show-off is definitely a bad practice. I would definitely keep the VS2008 that is standard for the rest of the team.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by checking out everything converting to VS2010 and simply not checking back in the sln or project files.

I would usually do the final build / test using VS2008 on a VMware machine.

Answer (score 0):

You must use different solution files for VS 2010 and VS 2008, but they can reference the same project files.  You don't typically add and remove projects from the solution very often, so this is a tolerable risk.  It's unfortunate there are 4 characters different between a VS 2010 and a VS 2008 solution file.  See http://robrich.org/archive/2010/04/20/working-with-both-vs-2010-and-2008-on-the-team.aspx